# Alternate Face Up Poker with Alice and Bob (on the floor)

Tags: game

I was so convinced that the "correct" answers to [this excellent](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15887/face-up-poker-with-alice-and-bob) question were wrong that I took out a deck of cards to prove it. Then I realised that I was changing one of the rules. So here's the alternate version with Bob's rules:

Alice and Bob are going to have a poker night. They have invented a variant where there are no secrets, and no randomness, called Face-Up Poker. Today, however, the table is full of work and so they're playing on the floor Here's how it works.

A standard 52 card deck is spread face up on the floor.

- Alice picks up any 5 cards from the floor. Bob does the same.
- Alice discards any number of cards, throwing them on the floor. She then
  picks up the same number of cards from the floor.
- Bob does the same. (He can pick up cards Alice discarded. This is the difference from the other question.)
- They then compare hands, and the best hand wins, with Bob winning ties.

> Which player can force a win? What is their winning strategy?

This puzzle assumes familiarity with the rankings of poker hands, but no other knowledge of the rules of poker. For a refresher these rankings, see [this helpful page](http://www.pokerhands.com/poker_hand_tie_rules.html) (the hands are listed worst to best from top to bottom).

Comment: Clarification needed: The cards Alice throws on the floor, are they counted as "face-up" being available to Bob or are they "lost" to the game?

Comment: To b eclear, the only difference with the other game is that Bob can take the cards that Alice discarded, correct?

Comment: @oerkelens - that's right the only difference is that Bob can take the cards that Alice discarded. This however changes the entire game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think Alice can win this version.

> All 52 cards are available to Bob, apart from the 5 in Alice's hand.
>
> If she starts with a royal flush, so too will Bob, making it a tie, meaning Bob wins
>
> If she acts in any way to block a royal flush, then it doesn't matter what Bob takes. Since she discards first, Bob always has the option to equal or better her hand.
>
> She either has 4 of a kind and Bob has a straight flush, or they both have a royal flush. Either way, Bob wins

To summarise enormously:

> There are is no five card poker hand you can remove from a deck of 52 cards that can't at least be equalled by another hand chosen from the remainder

Comment: Right. Actually, with the lack of discarded cards, it doesn't matter what either of them choose in the first round. In the second round, the highest unique (non-replicable) hand that Alice can choose is 4 Aces, which Bob can beat with a straight flush.

Answer (score 0):

Bob, by selecting a royal flush, and no discarding of cards? He has the highest combination possible, and he wins when Alice has the same combination.

Comment: I probably miss something essential, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You are only missing what happens if Alice blocks Bob's royal flush.